# Python3 print specific href links

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml, href

Im trying to get the script to scrape a site and only look for the hrefs that have *.php?id=* i can get all hrefs to print with bs4 but cannot select ones out of .php?id= and print them

```
<li><a href="#">Education & Research </a>
<ul>                         
<li><a href="caseofthe_month.php">Case of the Month</a></li>
<a href="page.php?id=2">
<a href="idontwantthispagetoshowup.php">
<a href="page.php?id=5">Prospectus Fellowship-July-14</a>
<a href="thisoneeither.php">
```

'''

```
def gethref(ip):
    url = ("http://" + ip)
    print("[x] ~ SCAN: " + url + " ~ [x]")
    req = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(req.text)
    tree_href = tree.xpath('//@href')
    #print(tree_href)
    if '*.php?id=*' in tree_href:
        print (tree_href)
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    #h = soup.find_all('href=*.php')
    #print(h)
    #sqli = soup.select('a')
    #for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #   sqli = (link.get('href'))
    #   sqli = str(sqli)
    #   print(sqli)
    #   if 'page' in sqli:
    #       print(sqli.a)
```

Comment: pls post your full code (including imports, what is ```html```?)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need to find all hrefs containing `.php?id=`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def gethref(ip):
    url = ("http://" + ip)
    print("[x] ~ SCAN: " + url + " ~ [x]")
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    h = soup.find_all(href=re.compile(r'(.*).php\?id=\d*'))
    print(h)
    # sqli = soup.select('a') # i don't know what its doing, so i just commented it out
    # for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #   sqli = str(link.get('href'))
    #   print(sqli)
    #   if 'page' in sqli:
    #       print(sqli.a)
```

I think this is what you need

Tell me if its not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `a[href*=".php?id="]`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<li><a href="#">Education & Research</a>

<ul>                         
<li>
    <a href="caseofthe_month.php">Case of the Month</a>
</li>
</ul>

<a href="page.php?id=2"></a>
<a href="idontwantthispagetoshowup.php">
<a href="page.php?id=5">Prospectus Fellowship-July-14</a>
<a href="thisoneeither.php"></a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select('a[href*=".php?id="]'):
    print(link["href"])
```

Prints:

```
page.php?id=2
page.php?id=5
```

---

Or:

```py
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if ".php?id=" in link.get("href", ""):
        print(link["href"])
```

---

Or:

```py
for link in soup.find_all(
    lambda t: t.name == "a" and ".php?id=" in t.get("href", "")
):
    print(link["href"])
```